# index out of range in while

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help with one thing, my program sometimes works, sometimes not. It's not working for those sequences of amino acids,

## when:

```
a = 'MEATPGYQDISALEKSVTYISLCFKVANAGSQLYTMAHKLHAVERSLEQTTMEQMDEMEVLELLESMSEVTNEYQNLRKDIREVQQLQRDVSSSIRYQMRSMQQTFHTLKQRIASSQKGRKKPEKGLDGAGVGIHE'
b = 'MRRGFAQSSKWLARNAKANLPTAVGAGIVPAPVKMGRSQYGRLLSLTKSEKWVLTAGIGCLVVSSAITMSVPLFLGKVIDVVFNKSGMDSAAMAKLGEYSVLLFGIFVLGGFANFARVHLFGNAALRIVRSLRSRLYRSMLMQEVGWFDTKGTGELINRLSNDTLMVGTSLSQNVSDGLRSVAMIGVGTGMMIYTSPQLAAVSALVVPAMAGMAIVYGRYVRRITKVELDKYAEIMKFAEERFGNVKTVKTFCREQQEVAAFDGKLDEALQIGYKETRARAIFFGLVRPKGKVLRKIIKICYPLFQTGFCGNFIIISVLYYGGTLVLQDSLTIGALTAFMLYAGYVAISMNGLSNFYSQLNKGIGASERIWEILDRECSIPIDKGVVPLEKPVGEVGFQNVFFTFPTRPESAVLTDFSLNLMPGTTTAVVGRSGSGKTTIALLMLRLYDPQGGTVHLDGIDLRTVNPQWLRNNIGAVSQEPVLFSCSIRENILYGANPGETPSPERLQQVIEDANVSQFTDQLPDGLDTLVGQRGMMLSGGQKQRVAIARALIKNPAILILDEATSALDAVSENLVQNALDNLIQGRTVLTIAHRLSTIRNADQIAVLSDGKIVEQGSYNELMGIQEGVFRELVASQAFGSRN'
a1 = len(a)
b1 = len(b)
```

and my program looks like

## That:

```
porownanie = True
for i in range(a1):
    for j in range(b1):
        if a[i]==b[j]:
            x1.append(i)
            y1.append(j)
            r=0
            while a[i+r]==b[j+r] and porownanie == True:
                dlugoscir.append(r+1)
                if r==3:
                    i1.append(a[i],a[i+1],a[i+2],a[i+r])
                    j1.append(b[j],b[j+1],b[j+2],b[j+r])
                elif r>3:
                    i1.append(a[i+r])
                    j1.append(b[j+r])
                r=r+1
                porownanie = len(a[0:i+r+1])<a1 and len(b[0:j+r+1])<b1
```

I have problem with command while, not all times, but with this sequence it shows string index out of range and i haven't got idea why. It should stop, when anything in command while is false.

Thank you for Advance

Comment: Which line has `string index out of range` error? Please show full trackback here!

Comment: It's `while a[i+r]==b[j+r]`

Comment: If `i+r` or `j+r` ever exceed lengths of their strings(there is no reason why it shouldn't given your code) it the call to access the string will give you this error. Double-check the logic in your code. Should be solved by requiring `i+r` and `j+r` less than al and bl repectively in your while condition.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#65>", line 7, in <module>while a[i+r]==b[j+r] and porownanie == True:

IndexError: string index out of range

I double checked logic, and i don't know what happened.
Sorawee, why do you think that's it?

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: I have to eliminate one point marks on my graph, i have something like that [link](http://wrzucaj.net/images/2016/03/02/af219762ae098a618ebdeb41530e758f.png) but also i need to have [link2](http://wrzucaj.net/images/2016/03/02/fa164d6ca3543cb1d94f6a291905110d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please don't write `porownanie == True`. `porownanie` is a Boolean value itself, so only `porownanie` is enough

The problem is `while a[i+r]==b[j+r] and porownanie == True:`. Python evaluates expressions from left to right, so when `porownanie` is `False`, it's supposed to exit the loop, but it got error from `a[i+r]==b[j+r]` before it could exit the loop!

The fix is easy: just switch the order

`while porownanie and a[i+r]==b[j+r]:`

By the way, this is a simpler version of `porownanie = len(a[0:i+r+1])<a1 and len(b[0:j+r+1])<b1` which is also more efficient:

```
porownanie = i+r+1 < a1 and j+r+1 < b1
```

because it doesn't need to construct a new list from slicing. Just an easy arithmetic calculation.

You could as well remove `porownanie` entirely and move the expression to the condition of the while loop:

```
while i+r+1 < a1 and j+r+1 < b1 and a[i+r]==b[j+r]:
    ...
```

Comment: @Dziabaduch: please also see another answer below. He uses a different terminating condition which is `while i+r < a1 and  j+r < b1` as oppose to my `while i+r+1 < a1 and  j+r+1 < b1`. Think about it carefully whether `while i+r < a1 and  j+r < b1` is what you want or not. I just tried to debug the error but preserve the semantics of your program, but if `while i+r < a1 and  j+r < b1` is what you truly want, fix it too!

Comment: Sure, i take a look, and while i+r < a1 and j+r <b1 is good one, i make a mistake with putting +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test that r does not cause the indexes being used to be too large.

You can make the test part of the while

```
while i+r < a1 and  j+r < b1 and a[i+r] == b[j+r]:
```

As we can see in the code.

```
for i in range(a1):
  for j in range(b1):
    if a[i]==b[j]:
        x1.append(i)
        y1.append(j)
        r=0
        while i+r < a1 and  j+r < b1 and a[i+r] == b[j+r]:
            dlugoscir.append(r+1)
            if r==3:
                i1.append(a[i],a[i+1],a[i+2],a[i+r])
                j1.append(b[j],b[j+1],b[j+2],b[j+r])
            elif r>3:
                i1.append(a[i+r])
                j1.append(b[j+r])
            r += 1
```

Comment: My teacher tells me that we shouldn't use break and he don't accept any program with it :/  but thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Dziabaduch OK I took out the break test and just left in the while test.